# Array of JTextField. Alignment in panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

[image: model]

Hello! I am trying to position an array of JTextField just like in the picture. I chose to make an array because I want to have as many fields as I want.

Now, the problem I encountered is that when I place the JTextFields in the panel it positions them vertically.

Is it also possible to insert the text fields in a scrollable panel?

```
private int nrFields=4;
    private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[nrFields];
    private JPanel panelNew = new JPanel();

    private void create() { 

        for (JTextField auxField: fields) {
            panelNew.add(auxField=new JTextField(30));
        }   

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");     
        frame.getContentPane().add(this.panelNew);      
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

EDIT:

I managed to solve the problem by placing the textfields in a panel, on which I set the layout to be boxlayout. Next I placed this panel in a scrollable pane, and this pane is placed in a new panel.

```
private int nrFields=10;
    private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[nrFields];
    private JPanel panelNew = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane newScroll = new JScrollPane();      
    private JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();

    private void create() { 
        newScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i=0;i<nrFields;i++) {
            panelMain.add(fields[i]=new JTextField(30));            
        }   

        newScroll.setViewportView(panelMain);
        panelNew.add(newScroll);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");     
        frame.getContentPane().add(this.panelNew);      
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code so that we know what you have tried.

Comment: So to clarify, you want a variable number of text fields in the center in a scroll pane, a text area above that stays in place, and two buttons below that are positioned on the left and right? What should happen of the user makes the GUI larger? I'm guessing more height should be given to the scroll pane. What about width? Should the space between the buttons increase? Should the text area and fields get wider?

Comment: For the moment I just want the text fields in a scrollable pane, vertically aligned.

Comment: Tip: Add @Raymo111 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's (basically) how I'd go about it.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.Random;

public class VerticalTextFields {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    VerticalTextFields() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,20,4,20));

        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 10 + r.nextInt(10);
        JPanel textFieldContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        /*
        While I do not see the point of this array, you may have 
        some purpose for it that is not immediately obvious, so..
        */
        JTextField[] textFieldArray = new JTextField[n];
        for (int ii=0; ii<n; ii++) {
            textFieldArray[ii] = new JTextField("Text field " + (ii+1), 40);
            textFieldContainer.add(textFieldArray[ii]);
        }
        JScrollPane textFieldScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textFieldContainer);
        Dimension d = textFieldContainer.getPreferredSize();
        textFieldScrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension(d.width, 200));
        ui.add(textFieldScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel textAreaContainer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        textAreaContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 50, 10, 50));
        textAreaContainer.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea("Text area", 3, 20)));
        ui.add(textAreaContainer, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        ui.add(buttonContainer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        buttonContainer.add(new JButton("Line Start"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        buttonContainer.add(new JButton("Line End"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                VerticalTextFields o = new VerticalTextFields();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a JScrollPane. And then call the setViewportview(Component). Then just place the JTextField in it. If you can post some code maybe I can help a little bit more.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do this. I created a JScrollPane, I set the VerticalScrollBarPolicy, and then I place in the JTextFields. The problem is that it places them over eachother.

Comment: Make sure your JScrollPane has a layoutmanager, something like the BoxLayout edit: Something like this should work `panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`